# ParentReference or Google_ParentReference

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-client

In Google documentation ( https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert ) has the following code snippets:

```
$file = new Google_DriveFile();
  ...
$parent = new ParentReference();
```

I am getting error in `Fatal error: Class 'ParentReference' not found`. I grepped the *google-api-php-client* for *ParentReference*.

```
lib: grep -R ParentReference ./ | grep class
.../Google_DriveService.php:class Google_ParentReference extends Google_Model {
```

It is seems that there are some prefix "Google_" added and *ParentReference* is renamed to  *Google_ParentReference* .

My conclusion is right? Is there something else I couldn't understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're right.

If you'll download latest [SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit) for [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) you can check that almost all classes have the prefix *Google_*.

For example, in folder `\src\contrib\Google_DriveService.php` you will find the definition of Google_ParentReference.

Also check *[Parents: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents/insert)* (Google Drive SDK).